# Visual Studio 2010, how to quickly grab an object as serialized XML? (while debugging)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm debugging code, and I have a strongly typed object that has around 30 properties. Is there a quick way to put the object onto the clipboard as serialized XML?

So in other words:

If I had the class definition

```
 public class myObj
    {
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

and was debugging these 2 lines of code:

```
myObj object = new myObj();
object.ID = 123;
```

Is there a way I can right click and "copy object as serialized xml".

to produce

```
<object>
   <ID>123</ID>
</object>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can make compromises and instead of the XML output you are just interested in a human readable output that can be copied as text. For example like this:

```
{ConsoleApp.myObj}
    ID: 5
```

Then you could just fire up the Immediate Window and write the name of the variable that you want to "serialize" to text.

---

**Disclaimer:** This was too long for a comment so I posted it as an answer although I understand that this does not directly answer your question.